# php update to mysql with array not updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that should be updating a row, no errors what so ever in the logs. From what I see it should be working. I took the function from a update user function and tried to mimic it for the new feature.

Here is the data array posting to it.

```
$data = array('id' =>  $vid, 'name' => $vname, 'logo' => $vlogo, 'info' => $vinfo, 'site' => $vsite, 'est' => $vest);
```

The post works, I am doing a dump on the updatecompany page. So they do get set. I think it may be with the function. Any insight would be wonderful!

```
public static function updateCompany($toUpdate = array(), $company = null){
  self::construct();
   if( is_array($toUpdate) && !isset($toUpdate['id']) ){
    if($company == null){
    echo "No company ID set!";
  }
  $columns = "";
  foreach($toUpdate as $k => $v){
    $columns .= "`$k` = :$k, ";
  }

  $sql = self::$dbh->prepare("UPDATE companys SET {$columns} WHERE `id` = :id");
  $sql->bindValue(":id", $company);
  foreach($toUpdate as $key => $value){
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    $sql->bindValue(":$key", $value);
  }
  $sql->execute();

  }else{
  return false;
 }
}



$vid = $_POST["idnum"];
$vname = $_POST["name"];
$vlogo = $_POST["logo"];
$vinfo = $_POST["info"];
$vsite = $_POST["site"];
$vest = $_POST["est"];
```

Comment: maybe this line `$columns .= "\`$k\` = :$k, ";` should be `$columns .= "\`$k\` = :$v, ";`

Comment: that didn't seem to do the trick

Comment: are all of the values in that array defined? There doesn't seem to be enough info here to help you figure it out

Comment: yes i just added that to show you, the var dump on the update page also shows them fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update SQL could not work because you have comma in update value set.

See, you attached comma without any consideration:

```
  $columns = "";
  foreach($toUpdate as $k => $v){
    $columns .= "`$k` = :$k, ";
  }
```

Then the final SQL will look something like this:

```
UPDATE companys SET `name`=:name, `logo`=:logo, WHERE `id`=:id
```

Do you notice the comma just before `WHERE`? it should not be there!

So you should update the code like following:

```
$columns = "";
foreach($toUpdate as $k => $v){
  if ($columns != "") $columns .= ",";
  $columns .= "`$k` = :$k ";
}
```

This should be working.

Comment: Both your's and @Rasclatt worked. I had another issue with the update   \Fr\LS::updateCompany($data, $vid); i never declared the $vid at the end i expected the array to take care of it

Answer (score 2):

I would maybe try using the bind array into your `execute()` method since you are just binding the values *(I assume this is PDO)*. Another feature is to use an array to assemble the column portions and implode at the time of use.

```
public static function updateCompany($toUpdate = array(), $company = null)
    {
        # Also this may supposed to be: self::__construct(); ?? Notice the "__" before "construct"
        self::construct();

        if(is_array($toUpdate) && !isset($toUpdate['id'])) {
            if(empty($company)){
                # Throw exception, catch it in a parent wrapper
                throw new \Exception("No company ID set!");
                # Stop, no sense in continuing if an important part is missing
                return;
            }

            foreach($toUpdate as $k => $v){
                $bKey        = ":{$k}";
                # I would create a bind array here
                $bind[$bKey] = $value;
                # I generally save to an array here to implode later
                $columns[]   = "`{$k}` = {$bKey}";
            }
            # Add the id here
            $bind[":id"] = $company;
            # I would use a try here for troubleshooting PDO errors
            try {
                # Create sql with imploded columns
                $sql = self::$dbh->prepare("UPDATE companys SET ".implode(",",$columns)." WHERE `id` = :id");
                # Throw the bind array into the execute here
                $sql->execute($bind);
            }
            catch(\PDOException $e) {
                # I would only die here to see if there are any errors for troubleshooting purposes
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

or to no need to be aware of last comma try this:

```
$columns = array();
foreach($toUpdate as $k => $v){
    $columns[] = "`$k` = :$k";
}

$sql = self::$dbh->prepare("UPDATE `companys` SET ".implode(',', $columns)." WHERE `id` = :id");
```